# What is SnapshotHelper on Windows Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Occasionally (rarely) my Azure website will freeze and eventually return 502 errors (seems like it takes 5 min). I see a whole bunch of items in my trace log related to 'snapshot helper'.

I haven't explicitly used this and google only seems to return results for VMWare. Anyone know what this is? If it is azure taking a backup of my site, is there some way I can schedule it for an slower time than 11:00 am EST?

```
SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotInternal - no new files in CodeGen
SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshot time since last: 01:19:59.9600775
SnapshotHelper::RestoreSnapshotInternal SUCCESS - File.Copy
SnapshotHelper::RestoreSnapshotInternal SUCCESS - process
SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotTimerCallback
SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotInternal - no new files in CodeGen
SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotTimerCallback
SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotInternal - no new files in CodeGen
SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshot time since last: 00:19:59.9866142
SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotTimerCallback
SnapshotHelper::TakeSnapshotInternal - no new files in CodeGen
```

Comment: Keep the bounty up for some more time. I am diving into it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have control over when backups occur, but you can add a second redundant VM so that users will hit this one if the first is unavailable.

Comment: I already have it set to autoscale images but that doesn't seem to kick in, and my site is low-traffic enough (and the problem infrequent enough) that i'd prefer not to pay for an additional VM if not necessary. So, upvote since that may work for some folks but not the solution. I have moved on from that project anyway, but if anyone figures this issue out I'd love to pass the info on to my former employers.